# Why won't the value I am searching in an Array return true even though the matching value exists?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, if-statement, foreach

I have been trying to figure this out for the last 3 hours.
I generate a random number, 0 - 36.
I also generate an array with the numbers 0-36 in steps of 2 (uneven numbers only).
I do a `var_dump` on both the random number and the array and I can see the matching value in the array, however, my `if` statement won't return true.

I also tried `in_array` and that did not work.  I tried `array_map`, no luck... I have googled endlessly and tried every thing I can think of.  What gives?

```
$this->number = rand(0, 36); 
$this->colorBlack = array(range(1, 36, 2));

foreach ($this->colorBlack as $this->color){

            var_dump($this->color);
            var_dump($this->number);

        if ($this->color == $this->number){
            echo 'yes';
            var_dump($this->colorBlack);
        }
    }
```

I would expect the above code to `return true` when the random number generated matches a value in the array, however that is not the case.

the Var dump looks like this:

```
array(18) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(3) [2]=> int(5) [3]=> int(7) [4]=> int(9) [5]=> int(11) [6]=> int(13) [7]=> int(15) [8]=> int(17) [9]=> int(19) [10]=> int(21) [11]=> int(23) [12]=> int(25) [13]=> int(27) [14]=> int(29) [15]=> int(31) [16]=> int(33) [17]=> int(35) } int(26)
```

Comment: What is coming out of your var dumps, for one example?

Comment: There isn’t a single `return` statement, so what exactly did you expect to “return true” here?

Comment: 'Yes' is not being echo'd--I should not have said "return true."

Comment: `$this->color` is an array, `$this->number` is a scalar integer. It makes no sense to compare them with `==` and expect equality here.

Comment: @04FS, thank you for your answer--can you please elaborate?  I am learning and I really am not sure what you meant.

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php `range()` already creates an array

Comment: @kerbholz, yes.  This is precisely the array I am trying to search through and see if any of those numbers match with the random number generated via `rand(0, 36)`

Comment: @dWinder nope.  Tried so many different ways and nothing has worked so far.

Comment: I guess `if (in_array($this->number, $this->colorBlack[0]))` still don't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) already returns an array, and you are wrapping it in an array again in this line:

```
$this->colorBlack = array(range(1, 36, 2));
```

That means that now you have an array with 1 item in it, which is the array that range returns.

When running `foreach ($this->colorBlack as $this->color){` this part `$this->color` will point to the first item, which is an array.

Then this line `if ($this->color == $this->number){` is comparing the number from the range with an array which is not working.

One solution could be to not wrap the return value from range in an array like:

```
$this->colorBlack = range(1, 36, 2);
```

[Demo php](https://3v4l.org/1O8Xn)

Comment: A wonderful explanation.  Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out.  Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are short one foreach loop, your values are nested so go one layer down, i.e.:

```
<?php
$number = rand(0, 36);
$colorBlack = array(range(1, 36, 2));

foreach ($colorBlack as $color){
   foreach($color as $k => $gotcha) {
       if ($gotcha == $number){
           echo 'yes';
           var_dump($colorBlack);
       }
   }
}
```